# Shifting of Symbols in a Column

Tags: r

**Reproducible Example**

`df <- data.frame("col1" = 1:3, "col2" = c(0.9, '9-', 10))`

```
  col1 col2
1    1  0.9
2    2   9-
3    3   10
```

**Expected output**

```
  col1 col2
1    1  0.9
2    2   -9
3    3   10
```

**Question**

I"m trying to replace all the *-* in a column and paste it in the front instead. Could anyone show me how to do this? Thank you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `sub` to capture the characters before the `-` as one group and the `-` as second group, in the replacement provide the backreference of the capture groups

```
sub("(.*)(-)$", "\\2\\1", df$col2)
#[1] "0.9" "-9"  "10"
```

---

Or using one capture group

```
sub("(.*)-$", "-\\1", df$col2)
```

Comment: Thanks Akrun. Could u explain how do i read \\2\\1 ?

Comment: @Javier  If you check `(.*)`, it is the block of characters that is captured as a group.  It is the first capture group, the second one is `(-)`).  In the replcement, we switch the backreference of the second first (`\\2`) and then the first so as to rearrange the substring within the string